# Applying Stokes' theorem on a 1-form with it's coefficients in $\mathbb C^3$

Tags: vector-analysis, differential-forms, stokes-theorem

$$ \mathbf{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(\mathbf u + i \mathbf v)$$
Here is a $\mathbf n$ is a complex vector ($\mathbf n \in \mathbb C^3$). $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf u$ both are real $3$ vectors.

I want to compute the line integral
$$\Im \oint \mathbf{n}^* \cdot d \mathbf n $$

Simplifying the integrand we find
\begin{align}
   \Im (\mathbf n^* \cdot d\mathbf n) =\frac{1}{2}\Im[(\mathbf u - i \mathbf v)\cdot(d\mathbf u + i d\mathbf v)] \\
   =\frac{1}{2} \Im(\mathbf u . d \mathbf u + \mathbf v \cdot d\mathbf v + i \mathbf u\cdot d\mathbf v -i \mathbf v \cdot d \mathbf u) \\
   = \frac{1}{2}( \mathbf u\cdot d\mathbf v - \mathbf v \cdot d\mathbf u) \\
\end{align}
The vectors $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf u$ are linearly independent vectors, so we can write
the differential of the last equation
\begin{align} 
\frac{1}{2}d( \mathbf u\cdot d\mathbf v - \mathbf v \cdot d\mathbf u) = d\mathbf u \wedge d\mathbf v = d\mathbf n^* \wedge\cdot d\mathbf n
\end{align}
Using [Stokes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem)
$$
\Im \oint_{\partial C} \mathbf{n}^* \cdot d \mathbf n =\Im \iint_{C}d\mathbf n^* \wedge \cdot d\mathbf n
$$
Here $C$ is a simply connected region with boundary $\partial C$.

I know very basic of exterior algebra. The book which gives a very brief review (Mathematical methods for physicists - Arfken) just tells how to deal with differentials and all the examples I worked out have 0-form coefficients.
This particular problem got me thinking that the Stokes theorem should work out for cases when the coefficients of differentials are not a 0-form. So in this case, the 3 vectors are the coefficients of the differentials and differentials are also 3 vectors.

From that line of thought if we think $\mathbf n$ and $\mathbf n^*$ are associated with orthogonal directions in some space then the application of Stoke's theorem is just a one-liner.

**Is this kind of proof permissible? or one needs to do more work to arrive at the proof.**

I found this integral here -

Berry, M. V. (1989). The quantum phase, five years after. Geometric phases in physics, 7-28.

Comment: What do you mean when you writet $\bf{d n^{*}} \wedge \cdot \bf{dn}$? What is the role of 'dot' here?

Comment: @vectorbundle This $\cdot$ is probably to make sure that the wedge product happens to certain components. $\mathbf n$ is a 3d complex vector, so this might be a possibility

Comment: There's no problem working with vector-valued differential forms. I would, however, raise the question of whether the dot product is real or hermitian.